# Can't add object to array in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object, use-effect, use-state

Java programmer new to React. I have code that does what it should right up until the `"setRf([...rf, {cat: category, fc: arr[i].functionalityCode}]);"` line in the `setRoomFeatures` function. I'm trying to instantiate the rf array with category and functionalityCode from the JSON when the page first loads.

```
import React, {useState,useEffect} from 'react';
import {API} from 'aws-amplify';

function RoomFeatures(props){
    const [ac] = useState([{fc:'Wheelchair Accessible'},{fc:'Accessible Lift'},{fc:'Infrared'}])
    const [av] = useState([{fc:'Lectern Microphone'},{fc:'Lapel Microphone'},{fc:'Handheld Microphone'},{fc:'Multiple Projection Content'}])
    const [gr] = useState([{fc:'Lectern Spotlights'},{fc:'Stage Spotlights'},{fc:'Presenter PC/Lecturn Computer'},{fc:'Lectern/Teaching Station'}])
    const [sr] = useState([{fc:'Fume Cuboard/Hood'},{fc:'Biological Safety Cabinet (BSC)'},{fc:'Incubators'},{fc:'Demonstration Microscope'}])
    const [rf,setRf] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        let params = {'queryStringParameters': {rc: props.rc} }
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const data = await API.get('roomslisterapi','/items/getRoomJSON',params)
            setRoomFeatures(data.item[0].rooms.roomConfiguration.item[0].functionality.item)
        }
    fetchData();
    },[props.rc]);

    function setRoomFeatures(arr){
        var i;
        var category='';
        for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            category='';
            if(arr[i].availability==="TRUE"){
                category=getCategory(arr[i].functionalityCode);
                if(category.length>0)
                    setRf([...rf, {cat: category, fc: arr[i].functionalityCode}]);
            }
        }
    }

    function getCategory(val){
        var retStr='';
        retStr=matchedCategory(val,ac,'Accessibility');
        if(retStr.length===0)
            retStr=matchedCategory(val,av,'Audio Visual Equipment');
        if(retStr.length===0)
            retStr=matchedCategory(val,gr,'General Room Features');
        if(retStr.length===0)
            retStr=matchedCategory(val,sr,'Special Room Features');
        return retStr;
    }

    function matchedCategory(val,arr,cat){
        var retStr='';
        var i;
        for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
            if(val===arr[i].fc){
                retStr=cat;
                break; 
            }
        }
        return retStr;
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <p>access: {rf.length}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default RoomFeatures
```

It doesn't add the object to the array. I also get "React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: '`setRoomFeatures`'. Either include it or remove the dependency array." Trying to find out what that means. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: How does `data.item[0].rooms.roomConfiguration.item[0].functionality.item` look like?

Comment: Just to check, are all the conditions leading to the `setRf` call being fulfilled?

Comment: Yes they are, everything is working as it should up until the setRf method. eg {category:'Accessibility', fc: 'Infrared'}. The setRf method just isn't working.

Comment: Ahh. Correction, it seems they are going in but only the last one displays in the return. I changed it to: <div>
            {rf.map((key,index)=>{
               return <p id={index}>access: {key.cat} - {key.fc}</p>
            })}
        </div> in the return only the last one enters so the call must be overwriting every previous one !

Comment: Fixed. Changed it to: setRf(rf => [...rf, {cat: category, fc: arr[i].functionalityCode}]); and it works now.